# How to read the access token without any user from Azure AD Application using client_id and client_secret in SPFX or Sharepoint Page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, spfx

Suppose I have created an Azure AD application and provided the necessesory graph permissions(Application Permissions) to it.

I want to write a code to create a Team in Microsoft Teams from sharepoint page/custom action.

As Example:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I want to hit the above api to retrive the access token from the AzureAD Application to use the MS-Graphs api in my Sharepoint page using javascript or spfx.**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for browser based client. Also, this is not secure to keep the client secrets in a page.

Two workarounds for you.

1.You can use the msal.js library, but this will need user interaction. Here is the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa).

2.Create your own server as a middleware. Request the access token from your server.